# operator '<' cannot be applied to android.widget.textview int

Tags: java, android, if-statement

I am building an app that can calculate BMI and analyze the results, so I have a switch-case added to the app to help it give advice based on the result. I have the BMI result displayed on a text view which I have made invisible, but I keep getting the operator '<' cannot be applied error in the case <15 and case >40 region of the switch. I guess this as a result of the string value in the textview, How do I fix this?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
public final static String EXTRa_MESSAGE = " com.blogspot.bosolutionsonline.bosolutionsbmi.MESSAGE";
EditText edit_height;
EditText edit_weight;
TextView ans;
TextView ans2;
int an2;
Button bmi;
double x=0;
double y=0;
double z=0;

/**called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initControls();
}
private void initControls()
{
 edit_height=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_height);
 edit_weight=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_weight);
 ans=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ans);
 bmi=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bmi);
 bmi.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick
             (View v) {
         bmi();
     }
 });
}
private void bmi(){
    x=Double.parseDouble(edit_height.getText().toString());
    y=Double.parseDouble(edit_weight.getText().toString());
    z=y/(x*x);
    ans.setText(Double.toString(z));

    ans.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()){
                case ans < 15:
                setContentView(R.layout.xml1);
                break;
                case 15:
                case 16:
                    setContentView(R.layout.xml2);
                    break;
                case 17:
                case 18:
                    setContentView(R.layout.xml3);
                    break;
                case 19:
                case 20:
                case 21:
                case 22:
                case 23:
                case 24:
                case 25:
                    setContentView(R.layout.xml4);
                    break;
                case 26:
                case 27:
                case 28:
                case 29:
                case 30:
                    setContentView(R.layout.xml5);
                    break;
                case 31:
                case 32:
                case 33:
                case 34:
                case 35:
                    setContentView(R.layout.xml6);
                    break;
                case 36:
                case 37:
                case 38:
                case 39:
                case 40:
                    setContentView(R.layout.xml7);
                    break;
                case ans > 40:
                setContentView(R.layout.xml8);
                break;

            }
        }
    });

    }

 }
```

Comment: why don't you use `if else` ? for `switch case` there is no comparison operator. if still you want then learn about `fall through case`

Answer (score 4):

Your switch case is testing the `v.getId()` value, so `case ans < 15` makes no sense for several reasons :

1. You should test `v.getId()` since that's the value you are switching based on.
2. You can't have comparison operator in a case clause, only individual values.
3. `ans` is not an `int`

A possible solution is to move the conditions to the default clause :

```
        switch (v.getId()){
            case 15:
            case 16:
            ...
            case 40:
            ...
            default:
                if (v.getId() < 15)
                    setContentView(R.layout.xml1)
                else if (v.getId() > 40)
                    setContentView(R.layout.xml8);
                break;
        }
```

I'm not sure how the value of `ans` should be used in this switch statement, if at all. Perhaps you intended to switch on some `int` value parsed from `ans` instead of on `v.getId()`.

Comment: added that line and error is gone. but any of my xml isnt launched based on the results displayed on the textview. the text view shows the result but no new xml is launched. why?

Answer (score 0):

if you want such thing try adding `default` case in you `switch` statement and then add `if else` statement as shown below:

```
       default:
           if(v.getId()<15){
              setContentView(R.layout.xml1);
           }else if(v.getId()>40){
               setContentView(R.layout.xml8);
           }
       break;
```

Comment: i added those lines you suggested and the errors are gone, thanks. but for reasons i dont know , on calculating the bmi and getting results, no new xml is launched, even if the result is displayed on the textview, but still non of the new xml are launched. for example when the answer in the textview is less than 15 xml1 is suppose to be launched, but it dosent . any clue

Comment: restart your activity

Comment: i done that already, even used an android phone to open the application but the anser gets dusplayed in the textview but no new xml launched

Comment: why that much xml? why don't you update the view only?